# On Real Hamilton Ring ..

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, normed-spaces

i know the definition of real hamilton ring

but if we said ,$ I$ is the ring of integral hamilton

what does this mean ?

what is the properites that word , integral , adds to the structure of hamilton ring ?

also , let $N$ is a function from $I$ to $Z$ ,$ Z$ is the integars

$N(a + bi + cj + dk )$ = $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 $ , $N$ is the norm

how can we prove that , $N(xy)$ = $N(x)$ $N(y)$ ?

i can prove that , $N(xy)$ = $c$ $N(x)$ $N(y)$ where c is rational number

but i don't know how to show that c = 1

any hints ?

Comment: Can't seem to find what exactly a "real Hamilton ring" is, although it looks like it's an analogue of the construction of the quaternions. Does it just mean "the quaternions"?

Comment: If my guess is right, then adding "integral" just means you are only considering the subring $\Bbb Z\oplus i\Bbb Z\oplus j\Bbb Z\oplus k\Bbb Z$. I don't think that would be considered to *add* structure, but it certainly limits structure somehow.

Comment: @rschwieb , what is the diffrence between $Z⊕iZ⊕jZ⊕kZ$ and hamilton ring ? how this limit the structure ? does this means that integral says that , $a ,b ,c ,d$ must be in $Z$ ? 
does this what you mean ?

Comment: yes , it means quaternions , real hamilton quaternions .

Comment: If a "Hamilton ring" is the quaternions, then it would be $\Bbb H=R⊕iR⊕jR⊕kR$, which contains $Z⊕iZ⊕jZ⊕kZ$ properly. It definitely has different properties than $\Bbb H$

Comment: Did you deduce $N(xy)=cN(x)N(y)$ without computing the boring product? If so, could you include that trick in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also define the "conjugate" of $x=(a+bi+cj+dk)$ to be $\overline{x}=(a-bi-cj-dk)$, then you can work out that $x\overline{x}=N(x)$, and that $\overline{xy}=\overline{y} \cdot \overline{x}$.

Then $N(xy)=xy\overline{xy}=xy\overline{y}\overline{x}=xN(y)\overline{x}=x\overline{x}N(y)=N(x)N(y)$.

This is slightly less messy than just grinding through the product of two generic elements :)

If you like the integral quatnerions, then you might consider learning about [the Hurwitz quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion).

Comment: this is the way which i tried to follow , but i couldn't prove that  $\overline{xy}=\overline{y} \cdot \overline{x}$. , all i could , is that showing ,   $\overline{xy}$=$c$ $\overline{y} \cdot \overline{x}$.
where $c$ is constant , how can we prove  $\overline{xy}=\overline{y} \cdot \overline{x}$.

 ??

Comment: i mean how to prove  $\overline{xy}=\overline{y} \cdot \overline{x}$.
 without , calculating $xy$ and this find their conjugate and compare it to $\overline{y} \cdot \overline{x}$ because this way is tiring and it's not anything but calculating ! so it's boring way !

Comment: I'm not really sure how you came up with the $c$. If you just grind through the product, you should wind up with equality and no $c$. I will not deny that it is tedious and boring, though :P You can mitigate that a little bit by just working out the formula for the product of two of them and then reusing it.

Comment: @MrWhy Actually Tharsis noticed the easy way to see that $c=1$!

Comment: my way with c fails ! ok ,so , there is no way without using the product ?

Comment: @MrWhy I can't think of one, but that doesn't mean there isn't one :)

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{I} = \left\{a+bi+cj+dk \in \mathbb{H} \mid a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ is the ring of integral quaternions, i.e., quaternions whose components are all integers. For example, $3+7i+5j+9k \in \mathbb{I}$ but $e+\sqrt{2}i+\pi j+\frac{5}{3}k \notin \mathbb{I}$.

We know that $N(xy) = cN(x)N(y)$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $x = y = 1 \in \mathbb{I}$. Then $1 = N(1) = N(1\cdot1) = cN(1)N(1) = c$, which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: hmmmmm , i noticed that c in my argument is N(xy)\(N(x)N(y)) ! so i think this line of reasoning is not going anywhere !